# Ionic Native Camera in browser

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4

I have an ionic app where i use it to scan a bar/qr code. It's working fine in browser and android itself, but how can i open the camera while accessing it using android browser?

I use phonegap-barcodescanner and cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova plugin is not available for the browser. Cordova plugin is something which communicates with native components of mobile phone e.g. camera. it's not possible to access camera using phonegap-barcode scanner in the android browser. I will recommend instead of PhoneGap barcode scanner use [ngx-barcode-scanner](http://npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode-scanner)

Link of sample project with demo: [ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner)